# Firebase Database, different rule for each data data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

in my Firebase application want to apply different RULES for different data.

ex: my data are

```
ContactUs
    -Ksdasda4sd
        name: "Ram"
        email: "ram@gmail.com"
        message: "Hello how are u"
HotelLocation
    -Ksdaseeesd
        name: "Hotel Name"
        address: "Near Highway"
        city: "Bangalore"
```

without login ContactUs data can be read write by public,where HotelsLocations can be read and write after login only.

on this configuration both need authentication.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

can is it possible

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

Comment: thank u, able to configure

Answer (score 1):

This is the configuration.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "contactme" : {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "true"
     },
    "HotelLocation" : {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: I have over 20 data sets. Tried this method, but it doesn't seem to work.